# vb.net writing files of specific size

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an application whereby I need to write files (many, many of them).  However, I don't want to write files that are too big because the program that consumes them will crash :)

Essentially, I would like to create files that are no larger than a specific size (possibly 5MB).  My data is of CSV format and I will be writing line by line or into some stringbuilder to create the file I need.

Question: Is there a way to write data and create a set of files that are no larger than a set size?

Comment: Count the length of bytes and limit it to about 5,120,000. Or split them by 5,120,000 each file.

Comment: I do understand that part.  What I don't understand is how to program that.  Do I use a stringbuilder and check every so often to determine?  Or do I check every time (which would consume resources).  Is StringBuilder the way to go or something else?

Comment: StringBuilder is handy and easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are creating CSV rows 1 at a time.

If you are using a StreamWriter on the file (hopefully you are, no need to hold it all in memory):

1. Create the new record (a string of CSV items).
2. Look at the StreamWriter's BaseStream.Length property (Caveat - You need to use AutoFlush to make that property correct with the data that's been written previously).
3. Add your stream position, new record's length, and your line separator's length (usually 1 or 2, depending on Cr, Lf, or CrLf), and see if it exceeds your threshold.
4. If no, write the line feed, the record, and continue.  If yes, close your StreamWriter and open a new one for a new file, write the record, and continue.